# Multi-Client Server in Java, Maybe threads not running properly or i dont know , cant find out why

Tags: java, server, client

I'm programming a server in java that broadcasts the Date() function each second to the clients. The problem is that it worked for only one client but as soon as I started making modifications for multi-client support it broadcasts the Date() only once and then stops, as if the function is being called only once. I can not find what I'm doing wrong so I will just paste the code and hopefully someone will spot the mistake. I searched online but only to end up more confused than I started. For Client program I use the tellnet terminal app for windows.

```
public class Server
{
    private ServerSocket SERVER;
    private int PORT;
    private Socket CLIENT;

    public Server()
    {
        PORT = 8818;
        try
        {
            SERVER = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server started on port: " + PORT);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void On() throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            CLIENT = SERVER.accept();
            new ClientHandler(CLIENT).start(); 
        }
    }
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

public class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket CLIENT;
    private OutputStream out;
    public ClientHandler(Socket CLIENT)
    {
            System.out.println("Accepted Connection from: " + CLIENT.getInetAddress());
            this.CLIENT = CLIENT;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            out = CLIENT.getOutputStream();
            out.write(("Time now is: " + new Date() + "\n").getBytes());
            sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(CLIENT.getInetAddress() + " has left the session");
            try
            {
            out.close();
            CLIENT.close();
            }
            catch(IOException j) 
            {
                System.out.println("Unexpected Error");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Server` class should not have a `Socket` instance variable. That should be a local variable in the accept loop. There isn't only one client, so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your modifications nearly worked - below is a running version with only minor modifications from your code.

A part of your modifications you unintentionally removed the while loop in the run function, which means the Date() function is in fact only called once. To see this, remove the while loop in run() and after the Date is printed (in the telnet window) the message "Done with the run function." is printed.

I added an identifier to each client which is printed with the date. The static cnt class field makes sure that each client has a different id.

I started separate clients in separate command prompt terminals using 
`telnet localhost 8818` such that they were running at the same time. At the bottom is the output from the 3rd client.

I did switch the code to camelCase convention (start variables with a lower case letter and capitalizing each new word) since all CAPS is usually reserved for constants and the change made the code easier to read for me.

```
public class Server
{
    private ServerSocket server;
    private int port;
    private Socket client;

    public Server()
    {
        port = 8818;
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started on port: " + port);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void on() throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            client = server.accept();
            new ClientHandler(client).start(); 
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket client;
    private OutputStream out;
    private int id;
    private static int cnt=0;

    public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
        System.out.println("Accepted Connection from: " + client.getInetAddress());
        this.client = client;
        id=cnt;
        cnt++;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            out = client.getOutputStream();
            while (true) {
                out.write(("Client " + id + ": Time now is: " + new Date() + "\n").getBytes());
                sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(client.getInetAddress() + " has left the session");
            try {
                out.close();
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException j) {
                System.out.println("Unexpected Error");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done with the run function.");

    }
}
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Server s = new Server();

        s.on();
    }

}
```

[image]